# Is it possible to compile MySQL from source without any or all of MyISAM, MERGE, MEMORY, or CSV engines.

Tags: mysql, linux, storage-engines

Is it possible to compile MySQL from source without any or all of MyISAM, MERGE, MEMORY, or CSV storage engines.

The documentation at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/source-configuration-options.html#option_cmake_storage_engine_options says that these storage engines are mandatory but then it also mentions about the `-DWITHOUT_XXX_STORAGE_ENGINE=1` option.

Let me know if it is possible to exclude any of these storage engines directly or through any tweak in the source code. Also, I am unable to figure how to use `-DWITHOUT_XXX_STORAGE_ENGINE=1` option. I am building the source code through the command

```
`BUILD/compile-pentium-debug`

`make install`
```

from the MySQL source code parent directory.

Comment: "Is it possible to compile MySQL from source without any or all of MyISAM, MERGE, MEMORY, or CSV storage engines." --- for what reason?

Comment: I just want to have the heap storage engine in my source code and remove all the redundant code.

Comment: any **real** technical reason behind that? What's wrong with having all default the engines?

Comment: I have to customize MySQL for my specific application, such that, it has minimum overhead on the system in terms of size, memory etc. Also, i want to make sure that it does not depend on any other storage engine while storing data in Heap.

Comment: the "overhead" of having another storage engine is practically nothing in comparison to the size of the data.

Comment: true, just wanted to know if its possible or anybody has tried it earlier :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MyISAM is absolutely mandatory in the code base; it's used for the internal system-tables (which MySQL will not start without) and also used for internal temporary tables used in some types of queries. You can't avoid it.

Even the (major) fork Drizzle has been unable to completely eliminate MyISAM